# Is Enfys Nest affiliated with anyone?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story, the-rebel-alliance

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, we learn that Enfys Nest and the supposed "marauders" aren't actually self-serving, but rather they seek to aid the oppressed and downtrodden, such as those on Savareen. I've seen the film twice so far and it seemed to me like Enfys Nest and company were just some random do-gooders. However I've seen several people offhandedly remark things like "that was neat how we saw the origin of the Rebel Alliance™ in *Solo: A Star Wars Story*" or "I thought *A New Hope* was Han's first time helping the Rebellion™, but I guess he did it first in *Solo: A Star Wars Story*". This all leads me to ask, were the "marauders" actually affiliated in any way with the  Rebel Alliance™ at the time of their appearance in *Solo: A Star Wars Story*?

Comment: I suspect that they are one of several groups which will make up the Rebel Alliance that we see in "Rogue One".

Comment: @Verdan - Indeed, along with Saw's zealots and a bunch of others.

Comment: People are reading too much into the word "rebellion". Just because Enfys Nest and the Cloud Riders are rebelling against the Empire, doesn't mean they are part of the Rebel Alliance.

Answer (score 4):

In current canon, the Rebel Alliance was officially formed in 2 BBY (two years before the events of *A New Hope*) in [a speech by Mon Mothma](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Declaration_of_the_Rebel_Alliance#Behind_the_scenes), in the *Star Wars: Rebels* episode "Secret Cargo". That formally brought together many existing rebel cells such as the crew of the Ghost and Phoenix Squadron (from *Rebels*) but some groups weren't invited/were disowned, such as Saw Gerrera's (as seen in *Rogue One* and *Rebels* again).

*Solo*'s scenes with Enfys Nest take place eight years prior to that, in 10 BBY, so her marauders definitely weren't associated with the Rebel Alliance at the time, since it didn't exist. They also seemed to be primarily focused on revenge against Crimson Dawn and other crime syndicates, rather than the Empire.

Comment: And some speculation that I'll throw into a comment - I would be *very* surprised if we don't see Enfys Nest and her crew eventually hook up with the Rebel Alliance somehow in a comic or a book or something. The scene in *Solo* wasn't the founding of the Alliance but it was clearly meant to imply they were off to do some serious rebelling.

Answer (score 2):

Enfys was closely allied with the [Alliance to Restore the Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alliance_to_Restore_the_Republic). It's not clear whether there's anyone that she *ultimately* reports to (other than her own sweet self), but in the closing pages of the film's canon novelisation we see her dropping the coaxium off with Saw Gerrera and his group of partisans. It's noteworthy that this is a mighty prize and that at this point in time, Saw was also strongly aligned with the Rebellion proper so it's likely that she was either told where to take it by Mon Mothma or just decided off her own bat that he was best equipped to use the coaxium to hurt the Empire.

> And it was probably for the best that she hid her identity even from her allies; it wouldn’t do for them to start doubting her because of her age.
>
> ...
>
> He actually came alone. Brave, Enfys thought.
>   **“Saw Gerrera,” she said, her modulator disguising her soft voice.
>
>   “Enfys Nest,” he said, glowering. “I hope you have good news for me.” He sounded as if he didn’t believe she ever could.**
>   “Refined coaxium, enough to power a fleet,” she said, gesturing behind her. “I trust you will put it to good use.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Solo: A Star Wars Story: Expanded Edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

The key is in the name 'Rebel Alliance'. Although Enfys Nest are rebelling against the empire, they are not the sole creators of the Rebel Alliance we see in A New Hope.

The Rebel Alliance is actually formed after the events of Solo and is made up of several Rebel factions with the overall aim to overthrow the empire. Enfys Nest is presumed to be part of this Alliance whilst there are also other Rebel factions that operate independantly from the Rebel Alliance e.g. Saw Gerreras faction known as the Partisans.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! If correct this is a nice answer, however, could you [edit] to add in some sources/evidence because at the moment there's no way to tell if this is speculation or canon.